# Getting error when trying to create texture object with linear interpolation enabled

Tags: cuda, textures

I have the following code set up to create my texture object :

```
int dimX = 512;
int dimY = 512;
int bits_x,bits_y,bits_z,bits_w;
bits_x = bits_y = bits_z = bits_w = 32;
cudaChannelFormatKind kind = cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned;
cudaArray *deviceArray;
auto channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(bits_x, bits_y, bits_z, bits_w,kind);
checkCudaErrors(
        cudaMallocArray(&deviceArray, &channelDesc, dimX, dimY, cudaArrayDefault));
        
cudaResourceDesc texRes;
memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
texRes.res.array.array = deviceArray;

cudaTextureDesc texDescr;
memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));

texDescr.normalizedCoords = true;
texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

cudaTextureAddressMode addressMode;
texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeMirror;
texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeMirror;
texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

cudaTextureObject_t texture_;
checkCudaErrors(
            cudaCreateTextureObject(&texture_, &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
CUDA error code=26(cudaErrorInvalidFilterSetting) "cudaCreateTextureObject(&texture_, &texRes, &texDescr, NULL)"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: you can make the error disappear by changing to: `bits_x = bits_y = bits_z = bits_w = 16;`.  Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182879/how-to-cuda-linear-interpolation-of-short-16-bit-texture-object).

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks, I did find that old post, but sadly this does not fix the error.

Comment: Try the example, in my answer, verbatim (i.e. copy/paste my answer into a new file, and compile it).  If that doesn't fix the error, please indicate the CUDA version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Linear texture filtering of integer data [is only possible when the texture is configured to return a normalized float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41182879/how-to-cuda-linear-interpolation-of-short-16-bit-texture-object?noredirect=1&lq=1).  Also see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#linear-filtering).  (Yes, I acknowledge that your example seems to compile and run correctly with your indicated read mode.
2. AFAIK, Linear texture filtering of integer data is not available for 32-bit integer components.  We can see some success with 16-bit integer components (or 8-bit integer components).

Here is an example that addresses those items, and compiles and runs without error for me:

```
#include <helper_cuda.h>

int main(){

    int dimX = 512;
    int dimY = 512;
    cudaArray *deviceArray;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<ushort4>();
    checkCudaErrors(
        cudaMallocArray(&deviceArray, &channelDesc, dimX, dimY, cudaArrayDefault));

    cudaResourceDesc texRes;
    memset(&texRes, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
    texRes.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    texRes.res.array.array = deviceArray;

    cudaTextureDesc texDescr;
    memset(&texDescr, 0, sizeof(cudaTextureDesc));

    texDescr.normalizedCoords = true;
    texDescr.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

    texDescr.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeMirror;
    texDescr.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeMirror;
    texDescr.readMode = cudaReadModeNormalizedFloat;

    cudaTextureObject_t texture_;
    checkCudaErrors(
            cudaCreateTextureObject(&texture_, &texRes, &texDescr, NULL));
}
```

(CUDA 11.4)

Comment: Thanks!! The key change was to use template version of `cudaCreateChannelDesc` and to set readMode to `cudaReadModeNormalizedFloat`.  The code I originally had was taken from the cuda samples repo on github, so perhaps that code should be updated to handle linear filtering.